# Align matching content in separate containers depending on width of largest content

Tags: html, css

I'm aware of CSS `Subgrid` being able to solve a layout like this, but what I'm looking to achieve is a list of containers with content inside. The content inside the containers is aligned right in the containers, but all the content is aligned (left) to the longest content.

Is this possible with `flex`? Are there any strategies to achieve this?

[image: Content alignment example]

I suppose the HTML structure would be something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="100px"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="300px"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="400px">All other content aligned to this longest content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="200px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code to make it easy for providing a suitable solution.

Comment: I've added basic structural code, but this question is more generic than just some bugged code...

Comment: it's possible with CSS grid (no need subgrid here)

Comment: Add your css code please.

Comment: I don't think there is any CSS code to add here - I'm looking for layout methods, not a specific code fix

Comment: You must try and whenever head to a problem, ask here.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what the best method to use is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely doable with flex.

What I've done is create 2 columns inside the `.container` element. Column 2 will be right aligned inside the container, and your `.content` will be left aligned inside `.column2`.

All you need to do to adjust the alignment of the content inside the containers, is to play around with the widths of `.column1` and `.column2` in the snippet below:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}

.column1 {
width: 30%;
}

.column2 {
width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">Container</div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="content" style="width: 100px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">Container</div>
  <div class="content" style="width: 250px"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">Container</div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="content">All other content aligned to this longest content</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">Container</div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="content" style="width: 200px"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Really neat solution! So column 2 is at the max size and everything shifts around that - nice!

What about when we don't explicitly know the width of our content?

Let's say that it's text instead of divs with widths - would is be possible to align them all dynamically? (without JS modifying the % of col 2) So everything aligns to the longest sentence

Comment: Yep. The widths given were only to show the darker boxes. If they all had text inside them, the width would increase or decrease accordingly, but the behaviour defined here would remain. The max width of the longest sentence would be the width of column 2. If your text goes past that then it will be wrapped to the next line, within column 2 itself. You can test this out easily. Just copy this code, get rid of the widths for the internal elements, and place in whatever text you want.

Comment: But let's say that you don't want the text to wrap, and you want the longest one to expand as more text is added - I don't think that's possible with flex right?

Comment: Expand in what way? Expand to fill in the remaining space on the left, or keep expanding towards the right?

Comment: Expand to fill the remaining space on the left, like if the text was pushing all the alignment to the left